# Bit wise 'AND' an array of registers in Verilog

Tags: bit-manipulation, verilog, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I have an array of registers/buses and a single result bus defined as follows.

```
wire [BW-1:0] bus_array[NUM-1:0];
reg  [BW-1:0] and_result;
```

where

```
parameter BW  = 4;
parameter NUM = 8;
```

I wish to perform a BW-bit AND operation on the elements of the array and assign the result to the register `and_result`.

I try doing this as follows.

```
integer l;

generate 
genvar m;
for (m=0; m<BW; m=m+1)
begin : BW_LOOP

    always @ (*)
    begin
      and_result[m] = 1'b1;
      for (l=0; l<NUM; l=l+1)
        and_result[m] = and_result[m] & bus_array[l][m];
    end

end
endgenerate
```

However when I simulate this in Modelsim 10.1e, I get the following error.

> Error: (vsim-3601) Iteration limit reached at time 2 ns

If I do not use the generate loop, and instead have BW instances of the `always @ (*)` block, the simulation works okay.

I can infer from the error message, that there is a problem with the generate for loop, but I am not able to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a bug with ModelSim. Reproducible on [EDAplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Fty) with ModelSim10.1d. Works fine with Riviera2014 (After localizing `l` inside the generate loop). I'm guessing that `and_result[m]` is somehow in the `@(*)` sensitivity list, which it shouldn't be.

`l` needs to be localized or it will be accessed in parallel with the generated always blocks; creating a potential raise condition.

One workaround is to use SystemVerilog and use `always_comb` instead of `always @(*)`.

A backwarnd compatable solution is to change `and_result[m] = and_result[m] & bus_array[l][m];` to `if (bus_array[l][m]==1'b0) and_result[m] = 1'b0;` which is equivalent code. This keeps `and_result[m]` only on as a left hand expression so it cannot be in the sensitivity list.

```
genvar m;
for (m=0; m<BW; m=m+1)
begin : BW_LOOP
    integer l; // <== 'l' is local to this generate loop

    always @ (*)
    begin
      and_result[m] = 1'b1;
      for (l=0; l<NUM; l=l+1) begin
        if (bus_array[l][m]==1'b0) begin 
          and_result[m] = 1'b0;
        end
    end

end
```

Working code [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/UCi)

Comment: Greg, I tried moving the integer inside the generate loop, but it did not help. I have also tried replacing the parameter BW in the generate for loop with a constant. It does not help

Comment: I just played with it on [EDAplaygrond](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Fty) with ModelSim10.1d, I can re-create the issue you are seeing

Comment: Wow [EDAplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com) is a good website. I was not aware of the presence of this website. Thanks for the link

Comment: @Prashant, I'm going to retract my answer as it does not appear to work. I'll put a link as a comment to the question.

Comment: @Prashant, I played with it a little more and found a work around solution.

Comment: I decided to use a modified version of your solution. Now instead of a `always @(*)`, I have a `always @(bus_array)` line, and this ends up solving the problem as well. The code this way is easier for **me** to understand. Thanks for your quick responses.